# Evaluate $\int_0^1f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $f(x)$ be an integrable function on $[0,1]$ that obeys the property $f(x)=x, x=\frac{n}{2^m}$ where  $n$ is an odd positive integer and m is a positive integer. Calculate $\int_0^1f(t)dt$

**My attempt:-**

Any positive even number can be written as the sum of two positive odd integers. So, $f(x)=x, \forall x\in \{n/2^m:n,m\in \mathbb Z^+\}.$ I know the set $\{n/2^m:n,m\in \mathbb Z^+\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Define $g(x)=f(x)-x$, if $f$ is continuous, I could say that $f(x)=x$ using the sequential criterion of limit. Hence,$\int_0^1f(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}$
How do I proceed for non-continuous function?

Comment: The question is vague. Are you saying that $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is a dyadic rational? What about other values of $x$?

Comment: Is the function Riemann integrable? If so, you can do it directly using Riemann sums. In every interval of a given partition you just choose a point of the form $\frac{n}{2m}$ (it is possible because such points are dense) and you will get a Riemann sum which coincides with a Riemann sum of the function $f(x)=x$. From here it is easy to prove the integrals of the two functions are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integbrable it is continuous almost everywhere. This shows that $f(x)=x$ almost everywhere (since the equation holds on a dense set). Hence the integral is $\int_0^{1} xdx =\frac 1  2 $.

Answer (score 1):

If we're using the Lebesgue integral, the value can be anything; simply define $f(x) = c$ outside the countable number of points you specify. If the Riemann integral is under consideration, the value must be $\frac12$, since Riemann integrability implies that $f(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere, so that $f(x)=x$ almost everywhere.